# date index from from multiindex for pandas dataframe

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, datetime, multi-index

I have a dataframe with multiindex which I want to convert to `date()` index.

Here is an example emulation of the type of dataframes I have:

```
i = pd.date_range('01-01-2016', '01-01-2020')
x = pd.DataFrame(index = i, data=np.random.randint(0, 10, len(i)))
x = x.groupby(by = [x.index.year, x.index.month]).sum()
print(x)
```

I tried to convert it to date index by this:

```
def to_date(ind):
    return pd.to_datetime(str(ind[0]) + '/' + str(ind[1]), format="%Y/%m").date()

# flattening the multiindex to tuples to later reset the index
x.set_axis(x.index.to_flat_index(), axis=0, inplace = True)    

x = x.rename(index = to_date)

x.set_axis(pd.DatetimeIndex(x.index), axis=0, inplace=True)
```

But it is very slow. I think the problem is in the `pd.to_datetime(str(ind[0]) + '/' + str(ind[1]), format="%Y/%m").date()` line. Would greatly appreciate any ideas to make this faster.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can just use:

```
x.index=pd.to_datetime([f"{a}-{b}" for a,b in x.index],format='%Y-%m')
print(x)
```

---

```
            0
2016-01-01  162
2016-02-01  119
2016-03-01  148
2016-04-01  125
2016-05-01  132
2016-06-01  144
2016-07-01  157
2016-08-01  141
2016-09-01  138
2016-10-01  168
2016-11-01  140
2016-12-01  137
2017-01-01  113
2017-02-01  113
2017-03-01  155
..........
..........
......
```

Comment: you are right, it is 10 times faster. But why? It virtually seems to be the same idea in the code.

Comment: @guyguyguy12345 yes, but there are too many operations there , also some functions  eg: `set_index` operates on the dataframe and not with index only. However this method just operates wit index list.